# DataQueryBuilder.setWhereClause(), android

Tags: java, android

I just cannot find the syntax of the setWhereClause and how it is used. Can somebody point me in a correct direction please?

Regards

Rhonwen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you provide a String containing an SQL style where clause without the WHERE keyword like one of these examples.

- "name = 'Joe'"
- "age < 30"
- "name LIKE 'J%' AND age > 20"

I think this is the documentation you are looking for:
https://backendless.com/docs/android/doc.html#search-with-the-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

Hi I finally got an answer. Thank you anyway. For those who has the same question... The syntax is below:

```
builder.setWhereClause("[COLUMN NAME] = " + "\'" + [VALUE YOU ARE SEARCHING FOR IN THE SPECIFIED COLUMN] + "\'");
```

Link: https://backendless.com/docs/android/doc.html#search-with-the-where-clause